# Allocate 64 KiB in Watcom C 16-bit DOS

Tags: ms-dos, memory, c, 16-bit

I'm trying to allocate a 64 KiB buffer in Watcom C 16-bit DOS. I'm using the "compact" memory model which [defines](https://users.pja.edu.pl/%7Ejms/qnx/help/watcom/compiler16/wmodels.html) the code segment to be limited to 64 KiB and addressed by near pointers (just offset), but the data segment to be addressed through far pointers (segment:offset).

From the documentation I also get the impression that using `malloc` in the compact memory model is simply an alias for `_fmalloc`.

However, when I try to allocate 64 KiB, or as close as I can get (1024 × 64 − 1, the maximum representable with a 16-bit `size_t`) the `malloc` fails. But when I allocate 64 KiB minus 32 bytes (i.e. 1024 × 64 − 32), the `malloc` succeeds.

How can I allocate 64 KiB (1024 × 64 − 1, i.e. 65535/FFFFh bytes)? And why does my `malloc` succeed when I subtract 32 bytes?

Comment: good point, so malloc(0x10000) == malloc(0x0) on this system.

Comment: Are you sure it's 32 and not 26? I'm looking at the OpenWatcom code, getting 26 by arithmetic, and failing to find my error.

Comment: @Tommy Yes, definitely 32 bytes. Are you in "compact" memory model? I'm not on OpenWatcom, but the original Watcom v11.0 (I will try to upgrade to 11.0c just in case).

Comment: @Tommy Just tested with Watcom 11.0c, definitely have to subtract 32 bytes.

Comment: Well I got my answer working forwards from https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/e69458539e84de181d5f23065e9024587b656f88/bld/clib/heap/c/fmalloc.c#L75 but obviously miscalculated `sizeof(heapblk)`. If I can find my error I'll turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Typically memory allocators need some extra data in addition to the requested allocation size. This is for maintaining a list of allocated blocks on the heap, it's usually a linked-list node along with a couple of other bits of info like if the block is currently allocated or free. This tiny structure usually goes behind the pointer returned to you by `malloc` and is typically rounded up to some power-of-2 size to ensure pointers returned by `malloc` are aligned.

Because of this, you cannot allocate exactly the size of your heap because we need additional space for that block's link structure.

For example, eight `malloc(8192)` calls would also fail on the 8th call because each allocation would occupy, in your case, 8 KiB + 32 bytes.

Comment: I'm not *entirely* convinced that eight 8K allocations would fail. There's no real reason why these would have to come from a *single* 64K segment. The arena data could be used not just to link together blocks in *this* segment but also link together whole other segments (32 bytes is pretty chunky for a block detail section when all you really need is a size, forward and back pointers and possibly a sentinel).

Comment: It depends on the implementation, I was deducing it was a 32 byte overhead from  the question above, which seems high to me, but it could be the OP didn't exhaustively test every size until it starts to fail. I suppose you could test it by measuring the address gap for 2 consecutive malloc calls on a pristine heap, or better yet dump the memory around your allocate to detect the presence of a embedded allocation link structure. I have no information on the actual malloc() strategy used here other than what the original question put forward.

Comment: Thanks Paul, for your answer. I'm sure you are correct but I'm looking for actual documentation from/by Watcom that would confirm this.

Comment: You could inspect the memory around the pointer that malloc returns: e.g.   void *p1 = malloc(256); memset(p1, 0xcc, 256); void *p2 = malloc(256); memset(p2, 0xdd, 256); --> Stop your debugger and dump memory around 'p2' -- You should be able to see if there is a gap between the 0xcc's and 0xdd's that the malloc subroutine inserted for housekeeping data.

Comment: I posted this comment under another answer but [here](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/a6882b7710215993d3fe64bf4fb4364b546cf091/bld/clib/heap/c/allocseg.c#L80) you can see where the 32 bytes comes from.

Answer (score 7):

I have not tried it but the following trick might work:

You can use `halloc(0x1000, 0x10)` to allocate a "huge" memory block of 0x1000 × 0x10 bytes (= 64 KiB) size. According to the manual this block will be 0x10-byte aligned if the second argument is 0x10.

`halloc()` can allocate more than 64K but returns a `huge` memory pointer, not a `far` memory pointer (see below).

In "Real Mode" ("normal" MS-DOS) the linear address is calculated as `0x10*segment+offset` so if the offset is a multiple of 0x10 (if the address is aligned to 0x10 bytes) you can calculate a `far` pointer that points to the same memory using the following method:

You take the offset, divide it by 0x10 and add the result to the segment. Then you set the segment to 0.

Example:

```
union {
    struct {
        unsigned short off;
        unsigned short seg;
    } s;
    void far *ptr;
} u;

u.ptr = (void far *)huge_pointer; // Example: 0x1234:FED0
u.s.seg += u.s.off >> 4;
u.s.off = 0;
far_ptr = u.ptr; // should be 0x2221:0000
```

Both `0x1234:FED0` and `0x2221:0000` point to the same memory.

However there are two differences between the pointers:

- `hfree()` and similar memory management functions must be called with the "original" pointer returned by `halloc()`, not with the "calculated" one
- The difference between `huge` and `far` memory pointers is that `far` pointers do not allow crossing segment boundaries: A `far` pointer to `X:Y` can only access (0x10000 − Y) bytes of memory. So a `far` pointer to `0x1234:FED0` can only access the first 304 bytes of the memory block (0x10000 − 0xFED0 = 304) while a `far` pointer to `0x2221:0000` can access the first 64 KiB (note that `halloc()` can allocate more than 64K).

Comment: This looks like a good solution to me.  The code for halloc is [here](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/master/bld/clib/heap/c/haloc.c) and it looks as though it *always* allocates aligned to a paragraph boundary, whatever the size is, anyway.  This is definitely a better solution than the one I'd have suggested (making sure not all DOS memory is allocated to the heap -- I'm not familiar with Watcom's tools, but there should be an option for how much heap to allocate somewhere -- and then using [INT 21h/AH=48h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2934.htm) to perform the allocation).

Comment: Another thing to note from the halloc code is that the returned pointer always has its offset set to zero, which should simplify the translation to a far pointer somewhat...

Comment: Another option is to just call `int 21h` function `ah = 48h Allocate Memory` directly yourself. This appears to be (from inspecting the code and stepping through it) what Watcom's library ultimately calls anyway to allocate more segments to the heap.

Comment: Since when does `halloc` return a pointer with offset != 0? Since you know your size is 64k you just cast it to a far pointer.

Comment: @Joshua The Watcom documentation does not say that the offset in the pointer returned by `halloc()` is guaranteed to be 0. For this reason, you have to assume that at least some versions of the Watcom library may return non-0 offsets.

Answer (score 3):

A community wiki answer because it includes a lot of useful evidence, but I seem to flub the numbers somewhere:

Per OpenWatcom, the definition of `_fmalloc` is [this](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/e69458539e84de181d5f23065e9024587b656f88/bld/clib/heap/c/fmalloc.c#L68). Notably:

```
if( amt == 0 || amt > - ( sizeof( heapblk ) + TAG_SIZE * 2 ) ) {
        return( NULL );
}
```

Allowing for integer rounding and [given that `size_t` is 16-bit](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/38bcff831948ff2defc26e0fca319a670c0a5717/bld/hdr/size_t.sp), that asserts that if the block you asked for is larger than `65536` minus `sizeof( heapblk ) + TAG_SIZE * 2` then the allocation will fail.

`heapblk` [is a struct](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/1c28685ea1d868e63d325897876b59be59daa7dd/bld/clib/heap/h/heap.h#L131):

```
struct heapblk {
    tag                 len;                /* size of heap (0 = 64K) */
    heapptr             prev;               /* segment selector/offset for previous heap */
    heapptr             next;               /* segment selector/offset for next heap */
    freeptr             rover;              /* roving pointer into free list */
    unsigned int        b4rover;            /* largest block before rover */
    unsigned int        largest_blk;        /* largest block in the heap  */
    unsigned int        numalloc;           /* number of allocated blocks in heap */
    unsigned int        numfree;            /* number of free blocks in the heap */
    freelist            freehead;           /* listhead of free blocks in heap */
#if defined( __WARP__ )
    unsigned int        used_obj_any :1;    /* allocated with OBJ_ANY - block may be in high memory */
#endif
};
```

And from line 50 of the same file, `TAG_SIZE` is just `sizeof(tag)`.

On line 106 `tag` turns out to be a typedef for `unsigned int` so it's also 16 bit.

`heapptr` is a union defined on line 115, of a `__segment` and a `heapblk_nptr` (a.k.a. a `_WCNEAR`). So it's two bytes as `nptr` means near pointer, and a `__segment` means 16 bit.

`freeptr` is a union defined on line 120, of a `freelist_nptr` and an `unsigned int`. So also two bytes.

`freelist` is a struct defined on line 125 consisting of a `tag`, and two `freeptr`s. So six bytes.

So a `heapblk` is 22 bytes of meaningful storage:

- 8 bytes for the four `unsigned int`s;
- 2 bytes for the `tag` (because it's another `unsigned int`);
- 6 more for the `freelist`;
- 2 for the `freeptr`; and
- 4 in total for the `heapptrs`.

That plus another 4 for the 2*TAG_SIZE is 26.

Therefore as posited elsewhere, you cannot allocate a full 64kb because some storage is reserved for heap management; however I seem to total that to 26 bytes, not 32.

Comment: I can’t see how in this case, but alignment issues sometimes explain surprising `struct` sizes...

Comment: Yeah, I kind of assumed that since everything is two bytes in size and it's a 16-bit machine, everything was naturally aligned. But maybe I'm wrong that everything is two bytes in size, or there's an additional alignment factor that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I can’t think of anything. But wouldn’t `sizeof( heapblk )` refer to [the `heapblk` `typedef`](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/1c28685ea1d868e63d325897876b59be59daa7dd/bld/clib/heap/h/heap.h#L111) rather than `struct heapblk`? (Yeah that doesn’t help solve the mystery at all...)

Comment: The reason seems to be that segments (where the memory is ultimately allocated out of) have a `heapblk`, a `freelist`, and `2 * TAG_SIZE` in them. They are allocated with `__AllocSeg` in `allocseg.c` and you can [see](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/a6882b7710215993d3fe64bf4fb4364b546cf091/bld/clib/heap/c/allocseg.c#L80) that one of the first things that function does is check against: `( sizeof( heapblk ) + sizeof( freelist ) + TAG_SIZE * 2 ) )` which is 32 bytes.